# How to find the maximum value?

Tags: angular, typescript

It is necessary to find the most suitable date (to display one value) based on this condition `c.date <= this.selectedReport.report_date`. But this part of the condition `if (Math.max(...this.costs.map(c => c.date))){}` does not work and because of this the data is not displayed at all. How can I fix this? There are no errors whatsoever.

```
reports: Reports[]
income: Income[]
costs: Costs[]
selectedReport = null
filteredIncome = []
filteredСosts = []

onSelectedReport(reportId) {
  this.selectedReport = this.reports.find(
    el => {
      return el.report_id === reportId
    }
  )
  if (this.incomeService) {
    this.incomeService.fetchAll().subscribe(
      income => {
        this.income = income
        this.filteredIncome = this.income.filter(
          (income) => income.income_id == this.selectedReport.r_income_id
        )
        if (this.costsService) {
          this.costsService.fetch().subscribe(
            costs => {
              this.costs = costs
              for(let i of this.filteredIncome){
                for(let c of costs){
                  if(Math.max(...this.costs.map(c => c.date))) {
                    if(c.costs_id==i.i_costs_id){
                      if (c.date <= this.selectedReport.report_date) {
                        this.filteredСosts.push(c)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          )
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Tried to use library [ngx-pipes](https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#readme). And removing this line from the loop `if (Math.max(...this.costs.map(c => c.date))){}` replacing it with it:

```
<div *ngFor="let report of reports" class="center " (click)="onSelectedReport(report.report_id)">
  <a>{{report.report_date | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</a>
</div>
<div  *ngIf="selectedReport">
  <div *ngFor="let i of filteredIncome">
    <div *ngFor="let c of filteredСosts | max: 'date'">
      {{c.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get this error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '-Infinity' of
> type 'number'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
> Arrays.
>
> atNgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck
> (common.js:3152)
>
> at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9246)
>
> at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
>
> at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
>
> at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
>
> at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)
>
> at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RepHoursComponent.html:48)
>
> at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
>
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)
>
> at callViewAction (core.js:10692)

Comment: Actually, you are checking the Math.max in the wrong place you should check for it inside the map.

Comment: @Hp_issei Something I do not quite understand, do you mean that?        `if(this.costs.map(Math.max( c.date))) {}`

Answer (score 0):

If `c.date` is Date JavaScript object try this `c.date.getTime()`

for reference [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the math.max check and apply as following.**

> (...this.costs.map(c
>   => c.date)) { if(Math.max(c => c.date)){ } }